# How do I activate Apple ID on iTunes Store via Web?

Tags: itunes, apple-id, podcasts

I want to publish a podcast show on Apple Podcast. Apple requires an Apple ID that is activated on the iTunes Store for this process.

I am running Linux on my computers and Android on mobile devices. I don't have any Apple device at all. Nor do I have access to a Windows PC running iTunes for Windows.

Now, how can I activate my Apple ID on iTunes? Is there an iTunes web frontend available? Can the iTunes Store be accessed without Apple OSes or Windows at all?

Comment: I don’t know if logging in to the Apple Music app on Android will qualify as an activation, otherwise you could install an unregistered Windows VM on your machine, but that would probably be too much a hassle...

Comment: Thanks @Harcker - I might give Apple Music on Android a try. Didn't know that it existed at all.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon the same problem using Ubuntu 22.04. I was able to activate my Apple ID using https://music.apple.com to "Follow the prompts to review and agree to the terms" as mentioned at https://podcasters.apple.com/support/827-create-an-account.

Then, a simple refresh on https://podcastsconnect.apple.com proved to be succesful!